# How do I add a 'Title' and 'Label

Tags: views, search

How do I add 'Title' to a search Engine? For Section 508 compliance i need to add 'label or 'title' to the following section :

```
<input placeholder="Search" type="text" id="edit-search-api-views-fulltext" name="search_api_views_fulltext" value="" size="26" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
```

I have created funtion.js with the following query:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
            $('#edit-search-api-views-fulltext').attr('title', 'Search');}
```

This doesn't seem to be working. View source says:

```
<div id="edit-search-api-views-fulltext-wrapper" class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-filter-search_api_views_fulltext">
                        <div class="views-widget">
          <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-search-api-views-fulltext">
 <input placeholder="Search" type="text" id="edit-search-api-views-fulltext" name="search_api_views_fulltext" value="" size="26" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
</div>
```

How do I add a Title?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can better do this with hook_form_alter. Like this:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $view = $form_state['view'];
    if ($view->name == 'my_view_machine_name' && $view->current_display == 'display_name') {
      // alter your exposed form here
    }
  }
}
```

If you do a var_dump (or dpm if you use devel) on $form, you can easily find out which values to alter.